# Update product quantity after place an order with my own Observer event

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, quantity, place-order, salable

I have created a new Observer event where I check sibling products. Sibling product are products with same pid.

After placing the order, I would like to reduce the quantity of siblings of the product too. My code works correctly, but only with the quantity of the product, the product salable quantity does not work correctly.

The product salable completely messes up my program. Can I update the salable quantity of the product to be sold instead of the simple quantity?

Please help me how to change the salable qty from my program code? I have been trying to solve this for days.